# angularjs access dynamically generated form field ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I generate form fields dynamically using ng-repeat.
Everything works fine.

But now I want to use angular datepicker component and it is based on a directive. The problem is that this seems only to work for static content/id attributes. In case of the dynamic ones I get "field.Key" - the placeholder value -, and not the generated id. (even if in the generated sourcecode on the client the id is correct)

I also tried ng-id or ng-attr-id, same result.
Any hints how to get this value in a directive, or another workaround?

Here is the sample code:

```
html
 <input id="{{field.Key}}" name="{{field.Key}}" type="text" date-time 
data-ng-model="field.FieldValue" auto-close="true" value="{{''}}"/>


js
 Module.directive('datePicker', ..., function datePickerDirective(...) {   
    return {     
      require: '?ngModel',
      template: '<div ng-include="template"></div>',
      scope: {
        model: '=datePicker',
        after: '=?',
        before: '=?'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       //generated value should be here, but is field.Key
       var pickerID =  element[0].id;
}
}];
```

Comment: Is the `date-time` attribute in the html meant to be `date-picker` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(element).prop('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it using

```
attrs.id
```

instead of

```
element[0].id
```